# Как удалить элемент массива javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

использую ajax для подгрузки данных вот функция

```
 $(document).on('change', '#Profile_id_category', function(){
    var id = $(this).val()

    $.post('/todo/get1', {q:id}, function(data){
        $('.list_tags').html('');
       if(data !== null){
              for(var i=0; data.data.length > i; i++){
                  $('.list_tags').append('<li class="tag">'+data.data[i].name+'<a class="del_tag"></a></li>');
              }  
                 $('.list_tags').append('<li class="input_li_search"><input type="text" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" style="width: 20px;" placeholder="" /></li>');
                 data_cache_edit = data.data;
                 data_cache_real = data.data;
            }         
    }, "json")
})
```

Полученные данные сохраняю в два разных массива

```
data_cache_edit = data.data;
data_cache_real = data.data;
```

Потом делаю событие удаления с массива data_cache_edit

```
$(document).on('click', '.del_tag', function(e){
    index = $(this).parent().index(); 
     $(this).parent().remove();
 if(data_cache_edit.length > 0 && data_cache_edit[index])    
    delete data_cache_edit[index]; 


 })
```

Но почему то удаляется и со второго массива data_cache_real. Я не могу понять как они связаны если я их нигде даже не приравниваю

Comment: Зато вы приравниваете их к одному и тому же объекту. Вот [краткий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/nrskqo6b/) ситуации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript передаёт объекты по ссылке. Чтобы "развязать" две копии, надо создать полноценную копию массива:

```
var data_cache_edit = data.data.slice(0);
```

Comment: Спасибо! не знал что связь создается по ссылке